# How do I change an "Upload" or "Choose file" button into an "Enter URL" or Drag Image box

Tags: html, image, file-upload, web-inspector

So I'm using this site called [Dithertron](https://8bitworkshop.com/dithertron/). It's a neat tool. I'm not trying to make a new site or anything, but I'd like to edit it for myself with the Inspect tool. It has a button to upload local files, which is cool and all, but I want to use online images.

One idea I had was to have a textbox for the url and button to register the url. I found this code in Stack Overflow. But it didn't work, I think it's too simplistic.

```
<input type="url" id="textbox" /> <input type="button" id="btn" value="Submit" onClick="window.location = document.getElementById('textbox').value;"/>
```

Another idea was to a have a box where you can drag the image onto the box as seen with [this ai image mixer page](https://cloud.lambdalabs.com/demos/lambda/image-mixer-demo). But I don't know how to do it.

I think the main thing is that I don't know how the site grabs the images and uses it for the program and I don't want to keep downloading images, just to upload them there,.